# Installing lower version(1.4) of django on already installed Django 1.6

Tags: python, django

I initially installed Django 1.6.5 on my Pc,now when i was trying to install 1.4 then i came to know that

> If you installed **Django** using **pip** or easy_install previously,
>   installing with **pip** or easy_install again will automatically take care
>   of the old version, so you don’t need to do it yourself.
>
> from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/install/)

but in mycase i am downgrading,and successfully downloaded the `1.4` using **pip**,but it is still displaying  the version `1.6` when i check.How to get rid of the `1.6`?

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv? If so, what is the output of ``pip freeze``? If not, you probably should be, but try doing ``pip uninstall Django``, and then re-installing Django 1.4.

Comment: Why you don't use a [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html)?

Comment: @DominicRodger no i am not using virtualenv

Comment: how did you install it?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham **pip install django 1.4**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use     `pip install Django==1.4`, the `==` specifies the version

Comment: **pip install django 1.4** works well too,except the error that **real name of 1.4 is 3-1**

Comment: @nobalG, no it does not, that installs the latest django and the tries to install a package 1.4, try it and see the difference, try pip install 3.1